# $(window).unload wait for AJAX call to finish before leaving a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Basically, once a user leaves a webpage in my application, I need to call a PHP script with AJAX, which will insert a time spent on the webpage to the database and then leave the page.

It is important to wait for the AJAX request to finish because webpages in my application are not accessible to users unless they have spent a certain time on a previous page (let's say two minutes).

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var teid = TEID;
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();

    $(window).unload(function() {
        var timeSpentMilliseconds = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
        var t = timeSpentMilliseconds / 1000 / 60;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/clientarea/utils/record-time',
            data: 'teid=' + teid + '&t=' + t
        });
    });

});
```

How should I change it so it will wait for the AJAX request to end before leaving the webpage?

EDIT:

Or it might be better (easier) to just let the AJAX request be repeated every minute or so. Is that possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well, you can set `async: false` on your AJAX call to make the browser wait for the request to finish before doing anything else, but note that this will 'hang' the browser for the duration of the request.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    url: '/clientarea/utils/record-time',
    data: 'teid=' + teid + '&t=' + t
});
```

From the manual:

> <sup>By default, all requests are sent asynchronous (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.</sup>

⚠ WARNING: This answer was posted in 2010 and is now outdated - the [XHR specification](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method) highlights the following statement:

> **Synchronous XMLHttpRequest outside of workers is in the process of being removed from the web platform** as it has detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. (This is a long process that takes many years.) **Developers must not pass false for the async argument when current global object is a Window object.** User agents are strongly encouraged to warn about such usage in developer tools and may experiment with throwing an "InvalidAccessError" DOMException when it occurs.

DevTools in Chrome has recently started warning about it, so this change (which has been coming for some years) could be imminent.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. I have updated my question. It might be easier to just let the AJX request repeat every let's say minute. How would I do that?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to avoid that, **especialy** on `unload`.

Comment: I have found there is always a better solution than doing `async: false`, regardless of the problem.

Comment: One problem I am seeing with this solution is that the request stays alive in the new page the user navigated to.

Answer (score 11):

The best solution is to use [navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon). It is brand new functionality which is starting to get implemented in new releases of browsers. The function is available in browsers newer than Chrome  39 and Firefox 31. It is not supported by Internet Explorer and Safari at the time of writing. To make sure your request gets send in the browsers that don't support the new functionality yet, you can use this solution:

```
var navigator.sendBeacon = navigator.sendBeacon || function (url, data) {
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open("POST", url, false); // third parameter indicates sync xhr
  client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
  client.send(data);
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this is elegant, i used it in Electron to send data when the app is closed

Comment: In 2018, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

How about setting a cookie in the unload handler? The server should see it on the subsequent requests.

```
<script>
    $(window).unload(function(){document.cookie='left_on='+(new Date())})
</script>
```

Comment: This is the best solution.  
• The user does not have to wait for the Ajax request.
• Data will be included on the next request to the server (one request, instead of two).
• Less code.
You can set the cookie to expire after a few seconds, and unset the cookie as soon as the page loads to avoid privacy issues with GDPR.

Answer (score 4):

for me, yours is not a good idea for the browser to wait before closing...

 simply because what if I really want to close it?...

if a page bother a user, it's not good...

my suggestion is, in the page, you wait for 2 minutes (if 2 minutes is the requirements), then send an ajax that the user has done his 2 minutes...

you can then check it on the server side if one has his 2 minutes or not...

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to try and hijack your users' browser, since it will give them a bad feeling and send them away.

If for some reason you want not to produce a new page until the user has spent a minimum time on the previous one, the best thing to do is to pilot server side, i.e. redirecting to the current page until the requested time has passed.

You don't even need to make ajax calls, just store in the session the timestamp of when the page was served, and don't show the following page until a certain amount of time has passed.

Be sure to tell the users they have to wait for a new page to be ready, maybe with a simple javascript countdown.

If you want the user to actually have the page active for a certain amount of time (i.e. not to switch to another tab/window waiting for the two minutes to elapse), well, I cannot propose an effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

use `onbeforeunload`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  window.onbeforeunload = function(){
     // $.ajax stuff here
     return false;
  }
});
```

This will at least bring the user a `messagebox` which asks him if he wants to close the current window/tab.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be much better to use a polling technique as you suggest, though it will cause some load on the web server.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var teid = TEID;
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();

    var ajaxFunc = function() {
        var timeSpentMilliseconds = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
        var t = timeSpentMilliseconds / 1000 / 60;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/clientarea/utils/record-time',
            data: 'teid=' + teid + '&t=' + t
        });
    };

    setInterval(ajaxFunc, 60000);

})
```

You'll be glad when you can use websockets :)

Comment: Thanks. But this will only get executed once after one minute? Could it execute repeatedly every minute (60 seconds)?

Comment: That's what setInterval does, as opposed to setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

The `jQuery.ajax()` method has the option `async`. If you set it to `false` the call will block until the response comes back (or it timed out). I'm pretty shure, that calling this, will yause the browser to weit in the unload handler.

Side note: You can't rely on this to work. If the browser gives the user the option to cancel the unload handlers (which some browsers do after a while of waiting), the "time spend on site" will never be updated. You could add a timer to the site, which periodically calls a script on the server and which updates the time.  You won't have an accurate value, but in your case, this isn't needed.

If you only need to know if the user was X seconds on the page You could simply set a timeout in the onload handler (using `setTimeout(function, ms)`) which makes a call if the user has spend the needed time. So there would be no need for a unload handler.