# $(window).unload not working as expected

Tags: javascript, chat

I'm making a small chat application with PHP + MySQL + JavaScript, I've written a function disonnectUser(), which is called when the user press the disconnect button. Here it is:

```
function disconnectUser(){
            $.post('web/WEB-INF/classes/handleChatUser.php',{ action: 'disconnect',nick: localNickname});           
            $('#chat').stop(true,true).fadeOut(2000,function(){
                nicknameDialog();
            });

            $('#messageInput').val(null);
            $('#clientList').html(null);
            $('#chatScreen').html(null);
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId2);
            connected = false;
        }
```

And it works like a charm, but when I call this very function in another context, when the user instead of pressing disconnect just exit the page, in this function

```
$(window).unload(function() {
                if(connected){
                disconnectUser();
                connected = false;
                }
            });
```

it doesn't work. And I'm sure it's being called, because if I put an alert it's called normally before closing the page. I think the page is closing before the code runs completely, so I think if I put some block there until the code finish running it would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of unload, how about beforeunload?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if(connected){
        disconnectUser();
        connected = false;
    }
};
```

Also, your `disconnectUser` method already sets `connected` to `false`, no need to do it here also.

It also seems that jQuery doesn't really handle the `beforeunload` event, which is why you'll need to revert to native JS to handle this:

http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/4e5b25fa1ff5e5ee?pli=1

Comment: You're right,i was setting the connected to false twice, thanks for this!!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `$(window).unload()` doesn't waits any AJAX call before closing the window (what is right *because AJAX is assync*).

You need to force the AJAX to be sync, ie, wait the response. Inside your `disconnectUser` function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: false, // This is the guy.
    url: '/blablabla'
});
```

You can read more about it here: [$(window).unload wait for AJAX call to finish before leaving a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138498/window-unload-wait-for-ajax-call-to-finish-before-leaving-a-webpage)

Comment: If I have fully answered your question, **please mark it as accepted**. If something still remains, let us know so we can complete the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a synchronous request. Perhaps in combination with `onbeforunload` like the other poster suggested. If that doesn't work, I suppose you're out of luck. A request that is synchronous blocks the browser while it's happening, so you might want to use it only for the unload function, assuming the method even works.

```
function disconnectUser(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'web/WEB-INF/classes/handleChatUser.php',
                data: { action: 'disconnect',nick: localNickname},
                type: 'POST',
                async: false
            });

            $('#chat').stop(true,true).fadeOut(2000,function(){
                nicknameDialog();
            });

            $('#messageInput').val(null);
            $('#clientList').html(null);
            $('#chatScreen').html(null);
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId2);
            connected = false;
        }
```