# Why "Session_end" not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

The event in the global.asax file is written like this:

```
protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = 5;
}
```

The code does not reach there when the client close the window, why?

Comment: Because that function fires when the session ends. Closing the browser window doesn't end the session. Check your session timeout value in IIS. I'd expect it to fire that period of time after the browser was closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The code does not reach there when the client close the window, why?

Because this event is not supposed to be invoked when the client closes his browser. This event (as its name suggests) is intended to be invoked when the session expires. The default session expiration timeout is 20 minutes so this event will be invoked 20 minutes after the client has closed his browser.

Oh and there's a very important gotcha you should be aware of: if you are using an out-of-process session state mode (such as StateServer or SqlServer) this event will **never** be invoked.

Comment: @Refael, do what? Detect that the client has closed his browser? That's impossible. You shouldn't be attempting to detect that. You could use javascript and subscribe to the [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event which will be invoked when the client is navigating away from the page.

Comment: i want to do something in the server when the client closes the application.

Comment: @Refael, you might want to do something but you can't. You cannot know on the server that the client has closed his browser. What do you need to do?

Comment: I want to close some connection when the client close the application.

Comment: connection with other server.

Comment: But what type of connection is this and why does it need to be closed? Also why not perform this task in the `Session_End` event instead of when the user has closed his browser? As I already explained there's no way to detect this event on the server so I guess you will have to rethink your design.

Answer (score 1):

P.S.:  The `Session_End` event is only suported by the `InProc` session manager

It gets called when your session get expired.

Answer (score 0):

I think your need is use a javascript function when page is closing or document unloding, that is [onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874182/window-unload-not-working-as-expected).And in that function make an ajax request to server indicating that client is closing the window.But you should be careful about security, because this javascript method registered at client side, malicious users can change the ajax request(even prevent it). If you dont consider any security issue, you are good to go.Good luck.

Comment: Don't forget that this event will also be invoked when redirecting away from the current page and not only when the user closes his browser which might not be desirable.

Comment: i know, but i bet he does not care about it :)

Comment: My problem with onbeforeunload is, when the user moves from window to window, it is also a runner, and I want it only when that application down.

Comment: @FredrickGauss, told ya :-)

Comment: Change your session timeout to 1 minute!

Comment: @Refael, you must read and experience with trying that windows form applications are not similar to web applications. When you say application, you dont know what is the meaning of it in the web part.