# Window.unload triggers post after unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do a post to server before unloading a page and I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011491/jquery-post-on-window-unloadwindow-or-browser-close) and it's working fine. My problem is the $.post on window.unload is triggered **after** it has unloaded. I tried it with a signout link and checking on my logs, I get the following:

```
Started GET "/signout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-22 00:15:08 +0800
Processing by SessionsController#destroy as HTML
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 1ms


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-22 00:15:08 +0800
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 12.9ms)


Started POST "/unloading" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-22 00:15:08 +0800
Processing by HomeController#unloading as */*
  Parameters: {"p1"=>"1"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:43:in `unloading'
```

First part is the signout and then user gets redirected to root **then** it runs the post ('/unloading').

Is there a way to make the '/unloading' execute first then execute whatever the unload action was?

I have this as my jquery post

```
$(window).unload ->
  $.ajax {
    async: false,
    beforeSend: (xhr) ->
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
    , url: '/unloading'
    , type: 'Post'
    , data: {
      p1: '1'
    }
  }
```

**Update**

So I did transfer the ajax request to beforeunload and it was working but I had to do a `return null` to remove the dialog box appearing because if I don't, the ajax was still triggering on popup of dialog (even without answering "yes/no i want to leave this page"). Result is this:

```
window.onbeforeunload ->
  $.ajax {
    async: false,
    beforeSend: (xhr) ->
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
    , url: '/unloading'
    , type: 'Post'
    , data: {
      p1: '1'
    }
  }
  return null
```

Also, I have only tried it with Chrome for now and it's working as expected. Yet to try on other browsers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the `beforeUnload` event

> The exact handling of the unload event has varied from version to
>   version of browsers. For example, some versions of Firefox trigger the
>   event when a link is followed, but not when the window is closed. In
>   practical usage, behavior should be tested on all supported browsers,
>   and contrasted with the proprietary beforeunload event.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

**UPDATE**

The unload event is triggered when the page has unloaded.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#XMLHttpRequests_being_stopped

**UPDATE 2**

To disable the `Are you sure that you want to leave this page?` popup try returning `null` from the `beforeUnload` callback function

- [How to show the "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" when changes committed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch)

**UPDATE 3**

Check this for cross-browser compatiblity

- http://jonathonhill.net/2011-03-04/catching-the-javascript-beforeunload-event-the-cross-browser-way/

Comment: Sorry if my reply was a bit uber late. I tried adding the whole ajax block to beforeunload before but it always asks a question first of 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?' with an [object object] as added message. I searched before and I think that was the purpose of beforeunload... how can I remove that?

Comment: And thanks for that info that unload event is triggered when the page HAS unloaded already.

Comment: Try returning `null` from your `beforeUnload` function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119289/how-to-show-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-navigate-away-from-this-page-when-ch

Comment: Yup. I did played around with it throwing in a number of values as well - false, undefined then null, and I've updated my post about that particular fix as well. I was just wondering, would it work on every browser (haven't got the time to test it out yet)?

Comment: Check this for cross-browser compatibility http://jonathonhill.net/2011-03-04/catching-the-javascript-beforeunload-event-the-cross-browser-way/

Answer (score 4):

As @NickKnudson suggested, use the "beforeUnload" event to post back form data before the window is unloaded:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  $.ajax {
    async: false,
    beforeSend: (xhr) ->
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
    , url: '/unloading'
    , type: 'Post'
    , data: {
      p1: '1'
    }
  }
}
```

Ran into exact the same situation about two weeks ago, switching to beforeUnload solved the problem.

Comment: Have you experiences any browser that window.onbeforeunload is problematic in?

Comment: No, but I haven't tested Opera and browsers running on OSX. Chrome, IE and all recent versions of FF do support it.

Comment: Sorry if my reply was a bit uber late. I tried adding the whole ajax block to beforeunload before but it always asks a question first of 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?' with an [object object] as added message. I searched before and I think that was the purpose of beforeunload... how can I remove that?

Comment: This normally happens if the bound function returns a value, may it be boolean, string or whatever. So do not return anything or possibly return null.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the window's `unload` event does not wait for AJAX calls (which are asyncrhonous) to complete prior to closing the window. In addition, jQuery doesn't seem to have built-in handling for the `beforeunload` event - which is why you will need to revert to native JS code to handle this. See below:

(**Note**: Written in *CoffeeScript*)

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $.ajax {
        async: false, // Important - this makes this a blocking call
        beforeSend: (xhr) ->
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
      , url: '/unloading'
      , type: 'Post'
      , data: {
            p1: '1'
        }
    }
};
```

[onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) - An event that fires before the unload event when the page is unloaded.

Also see this [Google Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jquery-en/Tlsl-h_15e4) discussion about this topic.