# How to use ajax with blueprints in flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I would like to define a global ajax function that I will use to unlock models in case a window closes unexpectedly.

```
@main.route('_unlockmodels')
def unlockmodels():
    .. unlock stuff ..
    return None
```

and then the actual ajax

```
function unlockModel() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "main/_unlockmodels"
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log('well see if your locks are gone', data, '<-- data?')
    });
}
```

Problem is, wherever I call this function from (in another blueprint) I get the following error

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/otherblueprint/page/main/_unlockmodels
```

How to specify where I am currently calling from (or other way to fix this)?

I call the function from within my page's `javascript` like

```
window.onbeforeunload = unlockModel;
```

Comment: Absolute URL? `"/main/_unlockmodels"`

Comment: Doing ajax before the window closes rarely works out the way you'd think.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative URL; it'll always be different depending on the current page URL. This has nothing to do with blueprints.

Use an absolute URL, or better still, have *Flask* give you the URL for the AJAX view:

```js
function unlockModel() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: {{ url_for('unlockmodels')|tojson|safe }}
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log('well see if your locks are gone', data, '<-- data?')
    });
}
```

The `url_for()` call returns a string with the proper absolute URL for the view you registered, and `|tojson|safe` produces a valid JavaScript string for that URL to insert into your jQuery code.

If your JavaScript is not part of a template, put the URL on an element in HTML that *is* generated by the template. Put it in a data attribute on the body, for example:

```html
<body data-unlockmodels="{{ url_for('unlockmodels') }}">
```

then retrieve that value from the body when you need to:

```js
function unlockModel() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: $('body').data('unlockmodels')
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log('well see if your locks are gone', data, '<-- data?')
    });
}
```

However, if you are trying to do this when unloading the window, you'll have to set the `async` flag to false to make sure it gets to complete before the page is torn down, see [$(window).unload wait for AJAX call to finish before leaving a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138498/window-unload-wait-for-ajax-call-to-finish-before-leaving-a-webpage):

```js
function unlockModel() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: $('body').data('unlockmodels'),
        async: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log('well see if your locks are gone', data, '<-- data?')
    });
}
```